# SAPUI5 controls the entire web page rendering

Tags: sapui5

I have been learning SAPUI5 Framework and from what I have learned, UI5 controls the rendering of all the HTML elements (apart from html, head and body).

Isn't it a standard (best practice) to have static HTML elements written directly in the web page instead of generating them through Javascript (via SAPUI5)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UI5 is NOT a closed framework in a sense that it "owns" the complete page and disallows application developers from creating their own static HTML. It is perfectly fine to write any amount of static HTML in the page and only use UI5 controls in certain areas. A potential good use-case is for example to do the overall page layout in plain HTML. You can also use the sap.ui.core.HTML control to write any amount of plain HTML *within* an area rendered by UI5 (e.g. within a certain part of a UI5 layout control).
So you can freely mix HTML and UI5 controls.

The HTML created BY the UI5 controls, however, is created dynamically, but that's how many JavaScript UI libraries work when providing higher-level UI elements that would be hard to write in static HTML. And also those libraries that offer templating (like AngularJS). So UI5 does nothing else than the de facto standard.
Some libraries, like jQuery UI are based on static HTML that will then be enriched by JavaScript, but even those may or may not dynamically add HTML.

Of course static HTML is always fastest, but also can get complex or impossible to write (when talking about tables with paging or growing lists).